# How to concatenate two fasta sequences by py

Tags: python, sequence-analysis, phylogenetics

I have three backbone and i want to concatenate 70 sequence into these backbone.
such like:
fasta file 1:

```
Backbone1: ACTGCGTATGTCAGCATATAGACCGCCT
Backbone2: CGTAGCTAGCTAGCTCGTGTCGTGATGCTACTC
Backbone3: GTCATGCTACGTGCTACGTGCTCGTCGCGC
```

fasta file 2:

```
sequence_1:CGCTAGTGTAGCTGCTACTCCG
```

output sequence:

```
Backbone1+sequence_1: ACTGCGTATGTCAGCATATAGACCGCCTCGCTAGTGTAGCTGCTACTCCG
Backbone2+sequence_1: CGTAGCTAGCTAGCTCGTGTCGTGATGCTACTCCGCTAGTGTAGCTGCTACTCCG
Backbone3+sequence_1: GTCATGCTACGTGCTACGTGCTCGTCGCGCCGCTAGTGTAGCTGCTACTCCGs
```

Comment: Use Biopython's seqio

Comment: Can you give me some tips for writing codes?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, those are not fasta sequences. Fasta is a specific format, and requires a `>` followed by a sequence identifier on one line and the one or more lines of sequence.

Assuming you really have two files in the format you show, you can do:

```
$ awk -F: '{ gsub(/ /,""); if(NR==FNR){bbone[$2]; next} for(b in bbone){print b$2}}' file1 file2 
GTCATGCTACGTGCTACGTGCTCGTCGCGCCGCTAGTGTAGCTGCTACTCCG
ACTGCGTATGTCAGCATATAGACCGCCTCGCTAGTGTAGCTGCTACTCCG
CGTAGCTAGCTAGCTCGTGTCGTGATGCTACTCCGCTAGTGTAGCTGCTACTCCG
```

The `gsub(/ /,"");` just removes the extra space you have in `file1` after each `:`. If you also want to have the sequence names as you show, use:

```
$ awk -F: '{ gsub(/ /,""); if(NR==FNR){bbone[$2]="Backbone"NR; next} for(b in bbone){print bbone[b]"+"$1":", b$2}}' file1 file2 
Backbone3+sequence_1: GTCATGCTACGTGCTACGTGCTCGTCGCGCCGCTAGTGTAGCTGCTACTCCG
Backbone1+sequence_1: ACTGCGTATGTCAGCATATAGACCGCCTCGCTAGTGTAGCTGCTACTCCG
Backbone2+sequence_1: CGTAGCTAGCTAGCTCGTGTCGTGATGCTACTCCGCTAGTGTAGCTGCTACTCCG
```

If you really need to do this in python for some reason, please edit your question and show us your python script so we have something to work on and expand. I really don't want to write a whole python program for something so trivial.